# Do I need to import the Thread class explicitly?

Tags: java, multithreading, compiler-errors

So, the following, very basic example of threading isn't compiling if i remove the import statement. However, earlier I didn't have to import the Thread class. Has anyone been through this, please assist me.

```
import java.lang.Thread;
class Test {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  Thread t = Thread.currentThread();

  System.out.println("current thread is "+t);

  t.setName("amar");
  System.out.println("after name change "+t);

  try {
   for(int n=5;n>0;n--) {
    System.out.println(n);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
   }
  }catch(InterruptedException e) {
   System.out.println("main interrupted");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you have another class named `Thread`?

Comment: What's the error message if you don't import `java.lang.Thread`?

Comment: no I don't have I am using the one provided in java.lang.

Comment: @tphobe9312 u have asked the question ??

Comment: The compiler says it cannot find symbol like the methods related with the Thread class (like currentThread(), sleep(), setName()).

Comment: u r using cmd to compile it ??

Comment: oh I got the problem once I created a class named Thread in the default package and it was this error now I have deleted the Thread.class created by me. Sorry

Comment: So when you said you didn't have a class called Thread you should have said that you did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not need to import any class in `java.lang`.  The class in `java.lang` are normally available to be used without an explicit import.

> "*A compilation unit automatically has access to all types declared in its package and also automatically imports all of the public types declared in the predefined package `java.lang`.*"  - [JLS Chapter 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html).

The only cases where it may be necessary to explicitly import a `java.lang` class are when you have declared another class with the same name as a `java.lang` class.  In some circumstances, *that* class may take precedence over the class in `java.lang`,  forcing you to either import the `java.lang` class, or use its fully qualified name.

It is a good idea to avoid declaring classes with the same names as commonly used Java library classes, especially those in `java.lang`.